# Best solution to implement "on-the-fly" client-server communication?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I apologize for the lame title but after 15 minutes struggling to find a better one, I simply gave up.
Imagine the following scenario:

- Desktop app `A` written in C# listens to user speaking and converts the `WAV` file into chunks (`byte[]`) **as the speech is happening**
- `A` then needs to send those chunks to server `B` (our Windows server) **as the speech is still happening**
- Server `B` waits for all the chunks to arrive (upon speech completion), then turns around and makes one HTTP POST to Server `C` (a 3rd party speech-to-text reco engine) with entire `byte[]` representation of the speech
- Server `B` gets the response and does some work with the resulting string, then sends back an object back to desktop app `A` (could be a string or image)

One of the requirements (statements in bold) is that, to increase efficiency, `A` should not wait for the speech to be completed before starting sending the chunks to `B`.

We put together a test solution that uses TCP sockets (seems to work okay) but since we have very little experience working with sockets, we are a bit reluctant (not sure about all the limitations).

**Are there any better suggestion to achieve our aim?**

PS: Another requirement, that still needs to be confirmed, may be that `A` be written in "unmanaged" C++ which would probably prevent any purely .NET implementation (like WCF's duplex services?)

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a few change to be made and I think it will improve the performance of the client/server.

Firstly, instead of sending the `byte[]` from `A` to `B` and waiting for all the chunks to be sent, you should send the `byte[]` from `A` to `C` then it waits for all the packets to be sent.

---

Here is a diagram that should help:

```
A -> C (waits for all packets) -> B (does some stuff to the string) -> A
```

---

And if you do not need server `B` then you could do something like this:

```
A -> C (waits for all packets, then does some stuff to the string) -> A
```

---

Here is what you are currently doing:

```
A -> B (waits for all packets) -> C -> B (does some stuff to the string) -> A
```

With the first idea you are only sending packets 3 times, the second idea only 2 times where as with your implementation you are sending packets 4 times. Although the amount of times you send packets does not matter in all cases, I think it will in this one because you need it to be `on-the-fly`. So sending less packets = faster response.

Hope this helps or gives you an idea!

Comment: Also, A would send it straight to C without waiting, then C will send all of the chunks to B.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matthew. I don't think either suggestion would work because I'm not in control of C, only of A and B. Therefore I can't have C do any "stuff" for me as suggested in #2 or have C forward the response to B as suggested in #1. Please let me know if I misunderstood your answer! :)

Comment: Ahh I see. If you cant have C forward the response to B then how will you get the response in your scenario? It says B makes a HTTP POST request to server C ... Server B gets the response.

Comment: B can only get the response from C if it makes the request to C.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a networking library which takes care of all the gory networking details for you (it's fast and asynchronous).

all you have to do is to manage the information sent/received.

Here is an introduction:
http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-networking-a-somewhat-performant-networking-library-for-net/